# Server side session state in dotnet core web api - How to benchmark and validate if it will benefit my application scalability?

Tags: asp.net-core, benchmarking, scalability, session-state, asp.net-core-webapi

Our team is writing an Angular + Dotnet Core 2.0 Web API project. We are expecting this application to scale rapidly in the near future and therefore have some questions below:

Is maintaining server side state using sessions in a web api project a good practice? I understand this is not how REST works however would like to find out if maintaining server side state would benefit my application. We are expecting this application to scale fast in the near feature.

Can someone help me with how to benchmark and find out numbers to validate our choice? - be it a REST ful approach where we send state with each request or persist session state at server and minimize request payload and database trips..? I don't know where to start hence seeking some guidance.

Comment: if you keep the session state in server you can not scale. How are you planning to distribute the calls when you need to add a new server?

Comment: @cool "if you keep the session state in server you can not scale." could you please provide more details why this can not be possible..? "How are you planning to distribute the calls" I believe the plan is to use load balancing for sharing the load and sticky sessions so requests are routed to the same server where their session state is maintained.. I personally have not came across this in my experience.. I am asked to evaluate how the application will perform in such a setup.. thanks!

Comment: I remember the times where we were using session state in server with sticky sessions but we are not using that approach anymore. It always depends on specific requirements and whether you have to maintain a legacy application/structure etc but if you want to keep session you can at least use an external component like redis to do that. So that you wont need session stickyness and you wont have any problem on adding new servers as your load increase.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core has built in support for distributed caching, which is also employed for maintaining session state. As a result, you can easily scale this functionality, if needed.

However, you're right that session state violates REST, and a well constructed REST API should not *need* state. What is it that you're thinking you need to persist across requests?

Comment: I agree with your sentiment. I have an .net core 2.2 app that currently has MVC and web api integrated under the same project. Is it possible to enable Session ONLY for the mvc side of the house and not the web api side (or ApiController as it's now called)? As I remember in MVC5 regardless of propriety, this was normal.